# Find Job by logged User with Pagination in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination

I want to find Job by logged User with Pagination in Spring Boot.

When i retrieve all Jobs for all Users, it works fine like so

```
public List<Job> findAll(Pageable pageable) {

        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : paginatedJobRepository.findAll(pageable)) {

            jobs.add(job);

        }
        return jobs;

    }
```

When i try to retrieve all Job by logged User with Pagination, it does not works fine. I make it like so

```
public List<Job> findJobByCompany(Pageable pageable) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        Company userCompany = companyService.findCompany(user);
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : paginatedJobRepository.findAll(pageable)) {
            if (job.getCompany().getId() == userCompany.getId()) {
                jobs.add(job);

            }

        }
        return jobs;

    }
```

The Problem is that , is doest not retrieve all Data with Pagination By User. The Pagination is correct but we can see the Data just in Paginate Page 5 and 6.
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: what does not work fine? Any exception? What is your problem?

Comment: @Patrick thanks for answers. i have update the Post

Comment: Try to use joins. You can achieve this with one query but instead you run three different queries. Also, instead of last one "findAll" write a method called findByCompany_id (I assume your Job entity has a relation with Company entity) and call that.

Comment: I think, that is not a Problem, because i get the Company for the logged user like so Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
  Company userCompany = companyService.findCompany(user); and here job.getCompany().getId() == userCompany.getId() check it if the company_id is same that the company_id in job

Comment: But you retrieve all the companies first and then do some filtering on the data. Instead, if you do that within a query, you'll get correct pagination result. Try Page<Job> findByCompany_id(long companyId, Pageable pageable)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner it works very fine now. with your trick Page<Job> findJobsByCompanyId(Long id);

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve all the companies first and then filter the results which is unnecessary and gives you wrong pagination values. Instead, define a method in your JobRepository as follows

```
Page<Job> findByCompany_id(long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

This method will create query like this

```
select j.* from Job j, Company c where j.companyId = c.id
```

And it also retrieves `count` of this query so that you'll get correct pagination results.

Comment: You are quite welcome, I'm glad it works. Remember to use '_' notation for joins. It is quite handy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom method with query. Something like this

```
public interface JobRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Job j join Company c WHERE c.id= ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM jobs j join Company c WHERE c.id= ?1",
    nativeQuery = false)
  Page<User> findByCompanyId(Long companyId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works very fine now.

Repository

```
Page<Job> findJobsByCompanyId(Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Service

```
public List<Job> findJobByCompany(Pageable pageable) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        Company userCompany = companyService.findCompany(user);
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : paginatedJobRepository.findJobsByCompanyId(userCompany.getId(),pageable)) {

                jobs.add(job);



        }
        return jobs;

    }
```